# React - Integrate google login using backend oauth provider

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth

I have oauth provider from backend server `..<ec2>.../oauth2/authorization/google` for google authentication. I need to use this link in react app and get the `JSESSIONID`.

Right now when user clicks on the above link first it will ask for login(google) after that redirects to `..<ec2>../info` page with user's information.

I add that link like

```
<Link to={props.googleAuthUrl} className="google-btn mt1">
  Sign in with Google
</Link>
```

Here, how will I know it is authenticated successfully and how to get the sessionid? How can I redirect back to my `localhost:3000` from `..<ec2>../info` page.

Comment: I fail to see how the question is related to either java or spring.

Comment: Its used in backend